# How does the instruction "atomic.fence" work on the code generated through LLVM "stackify pass"?

Tags: llvm, webassembly

I am trying to find some example cases regarding the WebAssembly instruction **atomic.fence**, but what I only found on the Internet are the test cases in the LLVM implementation of this instruction, and my question is how the "stackify pass" would impact the instruction order, and what is the equivalent WAT code of the below test code?

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/fdbff88196b54cea12deb1fae978277066dffd1e/llvm/test/CodeGen/WebAssembly/atomic-fence.mir#L44C1-L66C4

```
# In the two tests below, without compiler_fence or atomic.fence in between,
# memory.atomic.notify and i32.add will be reordered by register stackify pass
# to meet 'call @foo''s requirements. But because we have fences between
# memory.atomic.notify and i32.add, they cannot be reordered, and local.set and
# local.get are inserted to save and load memory.atomic.notify's return value.

...


---
# CHECK-LABEL: name: atomic_fence_test
name: atomic_fence_test
liveins:
  - { reg: '$arguments' }
tracksRegLiveness: true
body: |
  bb.0:
    ; CHECK: %[[REG:[0-9]+]]:i32 = MEMORY_ATOMIC_NOTIFY_A32
    ; CHECK: LOCAL_SET_I32 [[LOCAL:[0-9]+]], %[[REG]]
    ; CHECK: ATOMIC_FENCE
    ; CHECK: ADD_I32
    ; CHECK: LOCAL_GET_I32 [[LOCAL]]
    ; CHECK: CALL @foo

    liveins: $arguments
    %0:i32 = CONST_I32 0, implicit-def $arguments
    %1:i32 = MEMORY_ATOMIC_NOTIFY_A32 2, 0, %0:i32, %0:i32, implicit-def $arguments
    ATOMIC_FENCE 0, implicit-def $arguments
    %2:i32 = ADD_I32 %0:i32, %0:i32, implicit-def $arguments
    CALL @foo, %2:i32, %1:i32, implicit-def $arguments
    RETURN implicit-def $arguments
...
```